# Behavior of $n^a+a^n$

Tags: calculus

I was thinking about this and came to the following conclusion

$n^a+a^n$ behaves as $a^n$ for $|a|\ge1$

$n^a+a^n$ behaves as $n^a$ for $|a|\lt1$

Is this correct?
($n$ approaches infinity)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the opposite way ?

Comment: Yes, made a mistake when I was writing

Comment: My question still stands - is this correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Almost.

$n^a+a^n$ behaves as $a^n$ for $|a|>1$

$n^a+a^n$ behaves as $n^a$ for $|a|\leq1$

Comment: OP edited their question to what it states, prior to your answer, which repeats the OP's solution.

Comment: OP edited the question *after* my answer iirc.